# Ways to manage DB migrations with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, database-migration

I've looked at sqlalchemy-migrate, but it just seems like a lot of work and I haven't been able to find any useful examples.

Anyone care to share how they handle this?

Answer (score 18):

Check out new project Alembic: http://readthedocs.org/docs/alembic/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Please note Alembic also offers automatic migrations: http://rodic.fr/blog/automatic-migrations-sqlalchemy-alembic/

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any personal experience with `sqlalchemy-migrate`, but here's a tutorial:

http://caneypuggies.alwaysreformed.com/wiki/DevelopingWithMigrations

If you use the scripts mentioned there, you can create migrations like this:

```
./new_migration.sh "Describe the new migration here"
```

I do all my migrations with South: http://south.aeracode.org/
Note that it depends on the Django framework though.